# TFS2008 counterparts in TFS2010

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I used to invoke the ***BuildStore.asmx*** to get the build info from TFS 2008, such as work items, build steps, change set, etc.

But recently, our project moved to TFS 2010.  And the BuildStore.asmx is deprecated. TFS 2010 offers a new object model to provide these info.

So, in order to minimize the code change, I want to know the counterparts in TFS2010. Thanks for any hints.

I found some info about the build API in TFS, such as:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/09/14/getbuilduri-getbuilddetails.aspx

But they are mainly about TFS2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found some useful material:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/tfsgeneral/thread/92766815-c09b-422b-91fc-5e745e3aaa21

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of direct service-calls. The counterpart you re looking for should reside under "http://TfsName:Port/tfs/TeamCollectionName/Build/v3.0/BuildService.asmx".
Another, possibly far more efficient, approach is to write code against TFS-SDK, which should 'survive' from TFS-version to TFS-version. There are numerous resources out there regarding material, [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/01/11/tfs-api-part-33-get-build-definitions-and-build-details.aspx) article by S. Raiten seems to be a good jump-start.

Comment: Unfortunately, the counterpart service is not in that url.

Comment: This article provides with a full list of TFS services available: http://sbrickey.com/Tech/Blog/Post/TFS_2010_Web_Services . Everything notated as "v3.0" implies TFS 2010. I haven't a TFS 2008 installation available to test things out, but I'd guess that v3.0/BuildService.asmx is the one that fits better the profile you 're requesting.

Comment: Direct service call is not recommended in TFS2010.

Comment: You right, it's not. To my best knowledge, it not even recommended in TFS2008. In any case, investing with TFS 2010 on TFS-SDK implementations should yield with far more robust & time-persistent results.